# Understanding app thinning size report

Tags: ios, on-demand-resources, app-thinning

I have implemented the app thinning using on-demand resources. Now when the ipa is generated, i get a app thinning size report, which is as following

```
App Thinning Size Report for All Variants of App
Variant: MyAppName-iPhone 6.ipa 
Supported devices: iPhone 6 App + 
On Demand Resources size: 18.9 MB compressed, 37.8 MB uncompressed 
App size: 7.7 MB compressed, 26.6 MB uncompressed
On Demand Resources size: 11.2 MB compressed, 11.2 MB uncompressed
```

I do not understand what it means and how it affect my ipa size.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

37.8MB is the install size on device. 18.9 is the size of compressed IPA file. None of the above are the actual download size from AppStore.